# Using ST_snap to snap pairs of points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, snapping

I am using the following script to snap a set of point to another within a certain distance. The script works but there are some pairs of points that don't overlap even though the distance between them is smaller than the threshold. Anyone who knows where the problem could be? I attached a screenshot of one of the pairs.

```
update t set geom = ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001);
update e set geom = ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001);
 
with s as (
select e.id as id, st_snap(t.geom, e.geom, st_distance(t.geom, e.geom)) geom
from  t,  e
where  st_within( t.geom, e.geom, 1) and e.id=t.id

update table_name r
set geom = s.geom,
col1 =1
from s
where  s.id = r.id;
```

[image]

Comment: in your query you use st_within with 3 attributes, this is an error? St_within takes only 2 geometry, st_d_within take the radius with 2 geometry.